# How to find difference between two timestamp in Snowflake and result should also be timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

I have a requirement where I have to find time difference between two timestamp in snowflake and the output should also be timestamp i.e. it should have days, hour, minute and seconds(DD HH24:MI:SS).

Unlike Teradata snowflake doesn't support subtraction between two timestamp. Can any one please let me know the solution for this it would be a great help. Please refer below example for reference.

Timestamp 1: 11/23/2015 09:14:29
Timestamp 2: 11/5/2018 12:45:33
Expected Output: 1078 03:31:04.000000 (1078 is difference in number of days between two timestamp)

As per the expected output it should be in the format of DD HH24:MI:SS.

I have tried to use DATEDIFF function to find day, hour, minute and second difference but it's becoming too much complicated.

Comment: A timestamp consists of a date/time and you are asking for a duration in a specific format, therefore it is not possible to do what you want as a timestamp and a duration are not the same type of data

Comment: you are looking for an `interval`, I think?

Comment: Which database? I believe MySQL and Snowflake both support interval constants but not interval columns / results.

Comment: I have to find the difference between two timestamp and the output should be in DD HH24:MI:SS format. In Teradata we can simply subtract two timestamp but in snowflake I am not able to do that. So my question is that is there any way by which we can find difference between two timestamp and the output can be in DD HH24:MI:SS. I have also given one example in my question please let me know if anyone knows a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building this into a function to make it easier to use, but this takes the difference in seconds and days, uses the output of those to reformat the days and leftover parts to create a string in the format that you are looking for.  This is not a timestamp, since what you are asking for isn't a timestamp in Snowflake, it's just a formatted string.

```
select datediff(s,'11/23/2015 09:14:29'::timestamp_ntz,'11/5/2018 12:45:33'::timestamp_ntz) as sec,
       datediff(d,'11/23/2015 09:14:29'::timestamp_ntz,'11/5/2018 12:45:33'::timestamp_ntz) as days,
       sec::timestamp_ntz as sec_t,
       days::string || ' ' || to_varchar(sec_t,'HH24:MI:SS.FF6') as final_output;
```

It should be noted that a formatted string in Snowflake is probably not as useful as just querying the datediff in seconds and using that output in any other date math that you are probably doing, but since you didn't specify the final use of this output, I will assume you need a formatted string.